# ¿Cómo pasar un objeto/entidad en el constructor de una clase en symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, symfony3, identity, fos-user-bundle

tengo una duda que no encuentro como resolver y agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda

Tengo una clase Usuario en Symfony la cual tiene en su declaración unas entidades de sucursal y departamento

```
/**
 * Usuario
 */
class Usuario extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $apellidos;

……..
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Sucursal
 */
private $sucursal;

/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Departamento
 */
private $departamento;


public function __construct()
{


    parent::__construct();
    $this->activo = true;
    $this->fechaAlta = new \DateTime();
    $this->fechaModificacion = new \DateTime();
    $this->rol = "user";
```

En el constructor si puedo poner por defecto valores cuando el campo es no hace referencia a otra entidad pero no se como hacerlo para entidades

El id de sucursal y departamento es coincide que es = 1

He intentado usar el entityManager, doctrine pero creo que no se puede usar en el constructor
He intentado lo siguiente:

```
$this->em = EntityManager::class;
$this->departamento = $this->em->getRepository('BackendBundle/Departamento')->find(1);
```

También

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$departamento = $em->getRepository("BackendBundle:Departamento")->find(1);
```

También

```
$this->setDepartamento($departamento);
```

O

```
$this->setDepartamento(1);
```

El Set de departamento es

```
public function setDepartamento(\BackendBundle\Entity\Departamento
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar el `EntityManager` en la entidad es un *code smell* y no lo haría en ninguno de los casos.

Partiendo del diseño de la lógica de negocio: ¿un usuario puede no tener departamento o sucursal? En el caso de que la respuesta sea "no" y se le asigne un departamento por defecto, ¿qué pasaría si este departamento dejase de existir?

Propongo esta solución (lo expongo para "departamento", pero aplica también a "sucursal"):

1. Hacer *nullable* el departamento en `Usuario`.
2. Obtener el `Departamento` por defecto usando un `DepartamentoRepository`.

```php
// ...
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DepartamentoRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findMain()
    {
        return $this->find(0);
    }
}
```

3. Crear un `UsuarioManager` para persistir usuarios.

```php
// ...
class UsuarioManager
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $departamentoRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, DepartamentoRepository $departamentoRepository)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->departamentoRepository = $departamentoRepository;
    }

    public function update(Usuario $usuario)
    {
        if(!$usuario->getDepartamento()){
            $usuario->setDepartamento($this->departamentoRepository->findMain());
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($usuario);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Otra solución más estricta consistiría en inyectar el `Departamento` en el constructor de `Usuario`. Con esto, si por diseño todos los usuarios deben tener asignado siempre un departamento, evitaríamos posibles alteraciones del estado de la aplicación.

```php
class Usuario extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
    private $departamento;

    public function __construct(Departamento $departamento)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->departamento = $departamento;
    }
    // ...
}
```